# python 3.2.0 on win64, xml-rpc with large payload failing

Tags: python, windows-7, xml-rpc, large-data

I have a python object whose methods are currently being exposed via XML-RPC using the standard xmlrpc.server.SimpleXMLRPCServer (with the ThreadingMixIn, but that should not be relevant).

The server is running on Win64 as are the clients.  Some RPC methods return tables of information from a database to the client.  I'm finding that even modest blocks of data are overwhelming the OS and I get this kind of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "U:\Me\src\application\my_xmlrpc_client.py", line 1510, in __call__
    body = method(environ, start_response)
  File "U:\Me\src\application\my_xmlrpc_client.py", line 305, in q_root
    rows = proxy.return_table()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1095, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1423, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1136, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1151, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(resp)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1323, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 667, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: :[Errno 12] Not enough space">
LIBRA.rsvfx.com - - [19/May/2011 15:58:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Some research into the Errno 12 problem reveals that there's some issue with the underlying MS OS call and not with python itself:
http://bugs.python.org/issue11395

I'm not a very experienced XML-RPC developer; but is there some standard convention I should follow for delivering large payloads which would result in more, smaller writes (as opposed to fewer, large writes)?

And please remember I'm asking about buffer overruns; I don't want to have to debate why I'm using XML-RPC rather than rolling my own RESTful interface... I had to patch my WSGI application for this problem - sending small 1k blocks rather than larger blocks.  I'm not sure how to patch the XML-RPC application.

-- edit --

As requested, here is a code sample that reproduces the problem:

```
import xmlrpc.server
class RPCApp :
    def get_page(self):
        return ["data" * 64 for i in range(0,1024)]
if __name__ == '__main__' : # important to use this block, for processes to spawn correctly
    server = xmlrpc.server.SimpleXMLRPCServer(('127.0.0.1',8989), allow_none=True, logRequests=False)
    server.register_instance(RPCApp())
    server.serve_forever()
```

And the client code:

```
import xmlrpc.client
proxy = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://127.0.0.1:8989', allow_none=True)
print(proxy.get_page())
```

If you manipulate the page in the server to be small, then the code works.  As it is, the exception is thrown.

-- edit --

Seems to be resolved in python 3.2.1rc1.  Looks like we'll have to upgrade our installation....

Comment: The Python defect that you linked is only manifest when printing to a Windows terminal/console. I don't think it is relevant to what you are seeing here.

Comment: Also, any minimal code sample you can show/craft for us that will reliably reproduce or demonstrate this?

Comment: I am seeing the same issue using Python 3.2.1 as of the July 10 release.

Comment: @thechao: Strange!  We're using Python 3.2.1 (default, Jul 10 2011, 20:02:51) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 and not seeing the error any more.

Comment: @drone115b: Our problem was not properly matching utf-8 encode/decode with binary blobs and 'b' mode on files using 'with' statements. Once we got that all sorted out we no longer had problems.